# wordpress login redirect_to does not seem to work expectedly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

Should not this work as expectedly?

http://example.com/login/?redirect_to=http://www.cnn.com

Of course, this may seem like a silly example but should not redirect_to honor whatever is given to it?

In my case, I end up at the homepage. Am I doing something wrong here or is there a third-party hook that might be interfering with the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this http://example.com/login/?redirect_to=http://www.cnn.com to this http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://www.cnn.com

You can also use **login_redirect** filter. see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)

I think this is what you are looking for.

This will normally redirect all logins. To be able to redirect only when you want, you can use a query string parameter in the URL. Check for the parameter, if it exists redirect.

Comment: Thanks Tarun. I tried the wp-login.php which totally makes sense. But to my luck, it did not make a dent. I think there is a plugin involvement here!